# Writing a function to calculate the day of the week

Tags: python, python-3.4

My assignment is:

> Write a function to calculate and return h the day of the week (integer) given the year, month and day of the month. Using Zellers congruence

My code:

```
DAYS = ["Saturday","Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"]

if month == 1:
    month = 13
    year -= 1
elif month == 2:
    month = 14
    year -= 1

century = str(year)[:1]
century_year = str(year)[2:]

century = int(century)
century_year = int(century_year)

h = (day_month+((26(month+1))//10+century_year)+(century_year//4)+(century//4)+(5*century))%7

day = DAYS[h]
return day
```

When I try to run this i get

```
    h = (day_month+((26(month+1))//10+century_year)+(century_year//4)+(century//4)+(5*century))%7
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: `26(month+1)` - > `26 * (month+1)`

Comment: Thank you, that fixes my error but its not giving me the right date when i put in December 2nd 2014 it should give Tuesday but it gives Friday.

Comment: @NicolasPagnotta: That's a new problem. Don't expect to get answers by tacking followup comments onto existing questions. If you want to know what's wrong with your logic, write a new question explaining what your code is doing wrong and what you've done to debug it.

Comment: @NicolasPagnotta: However, one quick comment: `str(year)[:1]` doesn't give you the century, it gives you the millennium. Try it yourself: `str(2014)[:1]` is `'2'`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error could be in the multiplications.
h = (day_month+((26(month+1)...

when you write 26(month+1) Python thinks that you are calling 26 as a function with arguments month+1. You have to use the multiplication symbol "*".

try writing:
h = (day_month+((26*(month+1)...